# Blob encoding differences between databases

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using two databases, on one a typical WAMP server and the other is a local MySQL database. I am noticing that there are some differences in the way that each database is storing blobs, and I notice this when I export a row and compare each blob.

For example, when the local MySQL exports a blob, any 'NUL' ASCII character is prefixed by a '\', but this is not the case when exported from WAMP MySQL. So to match them I have to do (in PHP for a db export)

```
$val = str_replace(chr('NUL'), '\0', $val);
```

As I work through looking for more differences between exports, I also have had to do these as well

```
$val = str_replace(chr(0x9), chr(0x5c).chr(0x9), $val); 
$val = str_replace(chr(0xa), chr(0x5c).chr(0xa), $val);
```

And that was fine, for a very simple and tiny image. But I can imagine that there are a ton more differences I will encounter and I cannot account for all of them in a sane and timely manner. I am wondering what this is indicative of. Both tables are InnoDB engine and utf8_general_ci collation. What else could be misconfigured?

Comment: It sounds like SQL Anywhere is returning the results as a string, and is escaping the NUL bytes to avoid early termination of the string in languages that terminate strings with a NUL.  It also appears to be escaping other string control characters (9 == tab, a == line feed).  My guess is that it probably escapes other bytes that are below 0x20 as well.  Do you have the field defined as "LONG BINARY" ?

Comment: Thanks. One mistake I made is that both are actually MySQL. Both columns are of type 'blob'. The local MySQL dump command must be escaping these characters while the PHP command does not. Is there any simple solution?

Comment: So both are exporting differently, which makes sense.  Are you sure they are storing the data differently?  mysqldump outputs a text file, so I wouldn't be surprised if it escapes control characters.  PHP on the other hand, via PDO or mysqli_query would return binary, since the data is intended to be used by your php script.

What exactly are you trying to do here?  Import data from mysqldump via PHP?

Comment: Opposite. We are trying to import my PHP dump data into the local MySQL database. Without the escape characters, the import does not work. If I knew 100% which chars need to be escaped, I would be OK with just adding more str_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a good reason for not using `mysqldump` to dump data from the database, because that would be the best way to do this.

If you want to dump a blob out using a query in PHP you have a couple options.  You can use `SELECT ... INTO DUMPFILE fname` or `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE fname`, and provide a filename.  The MySQL documentation suggests using `SELECT INTO DUMPFILE` specifically for writing out blob fields to file.  There is also a `FIELDS ESCAPED BY` clause that can be used.  See the MySQL documentation for more information http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html .

If the `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` technique won't work for you, you could try to get the blob data from the database and escape it with mysqli_real_escape_string before writing it to your dump file.  That should sufficiently escape data so that it could be re-inserted into the database.  Keep in mind that the encoding needs to match on both tables.

Comment: It sucks that I am using PDO though. I wish there was an escape function that didn't require the mysqli connection. Furthermore i don't think I can manipulate any of the output further if I use INTO OUTFILE (which my client needs for some other fields..!)

Comment: Is there any way I can intercept the contents when i do SELECT INTO OUTFILE? I have no idea where this file is saving to (I am guessing the MySQL directory which I have 0 access to on this webhost)

Comment: I don't know of anyway you could intercept the contents of SELECT INTO OUTFILE.  You can however specify a full path to the file you wish to be written out, that way you can have it written to some directory that you have access to.